# mongodb reference for creating group based used access to an application

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I would like to build a project on User Access Application with the features like:

•         Create User 
•         Keep user in a group
•         Group is assinged to  particular application
•         Users belongs to certain group can access to applications that are assigned to them.

Now i am confused about creating user and group schema.

```
 var GroupSchema = new Schema({
  groupTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  users : [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User',  index: true } ]
});

var Group = mongoose.model('Group', GroupSchema);

module.exports = Group;
```

and user schema is

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
  password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    group:  [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group',  index: true } ]
});
```

Now i am wondering how to inject data into that array that I have created using ref. 
Thanks in advance.